# Magento2 How can I call a .phtml file in Observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

How can I call a `.phtml` file in an Observer?

I want to show a popup window when event Observer fires after customer login so I can call a `.phtml` file that contains HTML popup?

So after a customer has logged-in a popup appears on the screen that contains the string text.

Comment: which observer you want to call .

Comment: i want to call .phtml file from customerLoggedin observer @AmitBera

Comment: @Hiren, you got the any solution for that? Because I need solution for same question.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `customer_login` event for the block/template is not the proper idea.

The best idea in my view,

- **Create a cookie variable on event `customer_login`**.
- Then render **your block HTML output** if that you have that **cookie
  variable after redirecting from loginpost**.

**Observer class:**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename};

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class AssigncookieVariable  implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Cookie key 
     */
    const COOKIE_NAME = 'customer-just-login';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
     */
    protected $cookieManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
    }
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {

        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setPath(self::COOKIE_PATH)
            ->setHttpOnly(false);
        $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, $cookieValue, $metadata);
    }

}
```

**Stop block from output render when cookie value does not exit**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\BlocK;


class {YourBlockclass} ....
{
    /**
     * Cookie key 
     */
    const COOKIE_NAME = 'customer-just-login';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
     */
    protected $cookieManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

    public function __construct(
       ......
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        ....
    )
    {
        ....
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
    }

    protected function _toHtml() {
         if(!{CookieDoesnotExits}){
            return '';
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

}
```

**Call block via default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="{referenceBlockname}">
            <block class="{YourBlockClass}" name="{blocknameIn Layout}" 
            cacheable = "false"
            template="{template}"/>
        </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add DI in observer's construct function like below :

```
public function __contruct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context)
{
   $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
}
```

In execute function, add this code:

```
if(condition)
{
  $this->_layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Ex')->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::path/to/template.phtml')->toHtml();
}
```

This may work, not sure though.